# Understanding the google play console statistics

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

we are currently starting to evaluate the metrics of our app. For june we have the following statistics:

- Daily Device Installs: 1696
- Daily Device Uninstalls: 0
- Daily User Installs: 1421
- Install events: 1857
- Uninstall events: 1511

As far as I understood the documentation and various sources on Google the metrics are defined as follows:

- Device Installs: First time the app was installed on the device
- Device Uninstalls: First time the app was uninstalled on the device
- User Installs: The first time a user installs this app
- Install events: How often the app was installed (could also be multiple times on the same device)
- Uninstall events: How often the app was uninstalled (could also be multiple times on the same device)

If those are the right definitions then those numbers don't make sense to me.
If we have 1696 new devices with the app and 1857 install events that means that 1857-1696 = 161 times the app was installed more than one time on the device. If now the uninstall events are that much higher (1511-161 = 1350) it means that we have a lot of user who uninstalled our app. Since the device uninstalls equals 0 this mus mean that those user regularly delete our app, right?

When comparing those numbers to the months before we have a similar picture (also device uninstalls = 0  and the uninstall events much higher.

So I assume I have some misunderstanding somewhere.. can anyone explain where I'm wrong in my assumptions?

Best regards,
André

Comment: Have same problem with google play console statistics, it doesn't even match GA stats...